# How to implement primary key / foreign key between two parse tables?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, primary-key, foreign-key-relationship

Is there a way to make primary key and foreign key relationship with Parse tables? If yes, how?

I've two tables:

#### User Table:

> uId (primary key/string) | uName (string) | uAge (number) | uGender (string) | uLocation (string)

#### Employment Table:

> eId (unique/string) | eType (number) | eSalary (number) | uId (foreign key/string)

So that, if I'll delete an entry from User table, it'll delete all entries for that particular user in Employment table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `objectId` created by parse is the unique identifier. There is no concept of a primary key from the point of view of indexing, just unique identification.

A pointer or relationship is the approach you should use to `foreign key linking`. This is effectively a link to the foreign object `objectId`.

There is no automatic deletion logic. To accomplish that you would use a [before delete](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud-code-beforedelete-triggers) cloud trigger to process and cascade the deletion to the linked objects.